# how to fix error of adding unnecessary element in "group by" clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query in which I am fetching multiple_barcodes via comma separated. I am receiving error `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'prod_test.products.id' isn't in GROUP BY` when I put `products.id` in group by clause it gives me error `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'prod_test.products.name' isn't in GROUP BY`, seems like I have to group by each element in mentioned in select statement. Is there any way out of handling this kind of issue. Below is my query:

```
return Product::select(
            'products.id',
            'products.name',
            'products.name_ur',
            'products.barcode',
            'products.unit',
            'products.category_id',
            'products.image',
            'vendor_products.trade_price',
            'products.desc',
            'categories.name as category_name',
            'vendor_categories.category_status as category_status',
            DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(products_barcodes.barcode SEPARATOR ',')) as multiple_barcodes")
        )
        ->leftJoin('vendor_products', function($join){
            $join->on('products.id', '=','vendor_products.product_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('products_barcodes', function($join){
            $join->on('products.id','=','products_barcodes.product_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('categories', function($join){
            $join->on('products.category_id','=','categories.id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('vendor_categories', function($join){
            $join->on('categories.id', '=', 'vendor_categories.category_id');
        })
        ->where('products.barcode', $barcode)
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->first();
```

Comment: you have to select `products_barcodes.product_id` first

Comment: did you see the query ? i have already selected it

Comment: I saw your query, but I didn't see `products_barcodes.product_id` selected

Comment: The point of the query is lost on me. Your application code is perfectly good at rearranging arrays; there's just no need to do this kind of thing (GROUP_CONCAT)in your query

Answer (score 0):

You were missing 'products_barcodes.product_id' from the select list

```
return Product::select(
            'products.id',
            'products.name',
            'products.name_ur',
            'products.barcode',
            'products.unit',
            'products.category_id',
            'products.image',
            'products_barcodes.product_id',
            'vendor_products.trade_price',
            'products.desc',
            'categories.name as category_name',
            'vendor_categories.category_status as category_status',
            DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(products_barcodes.barcode SEPARATOR ',')) as multiple_barcodes")
        )
        ->leftJoin('vendor_products', function($join){
            $join->on('products.id', '=','vendor_products.product_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('products_barcodes', function($join){
            $join->on('products.id','=','products_barcodes.product_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('categories', function($join){
            $join->on('products.category_id','=','categories.id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('vendor_categories', function($join){
            $join->on('categories.id', '=', 'vendor_categories.category_id');
        })
        ->where('products.barcode', $barcode)
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->first();
```